# C++: An abstract class as a member

Tags: c++, coding-style, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have a question about style. I have a class (in my case an Option) that depends on the value of an exogenous object (Interest Rate). My goal is to create a abstract base class for the exogenous object (Rate) so that I can construct variations, say SimulatedRate or ConstantRate, that will work inside my depending class, Option.

However, I'm finding in C++, since I obviously cannot instantiate a abstract base class, I must store either a pointer or a reference to the base class. My concern is that when the instantiated exogenous objects go out of scope outside of the dependent class, my dependent class will be pointing to junk.

Is there a reasonable way to utilize polymorphism for this problem in C++?

My current code:

```
class Dependent 
{
public:
    Dependent(const Exogenous& exo) : exo_(exo) {}
    double getSomething() const { exo_.interfaceMethod(); }
private:
    Exogenous& exo_;
}

class Exogenous
{
public:
    virtual double interfaceMethod() const=0;
}

class ExogenousVariationA
{
public:
    virtual double interfaceMethod() const { return resultA; }
}

class ExogenousVariationB
{
public:
    virtual double interfaceMethod() const { return resultB; }
}
```

Comment: Shall `Dependent` necessarily hold a reference to `Exogenous`, or can it derive from it? Ie. Do you have to instantiate both classes separately?

Comment: Firstly, polymorphic objects are always held by pointer/reference. Even in other languages like Java this is the case. Secondly, since this is C++ you should always use the proper C++/RAII object lifetime management, which for pointers means smart pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sftrabbit has some good advice, to which I'd add:

- you could create a `virtual` `clone()` method in the abstract base class (it's not a *virtual* base class - that's something else entirely); that method would be implemented in the derived interest rate classes, returning a pointer to a new independent interest rate object that can be owned by the Option; this is particularly useful if the objects contain data that changes as you use it (e.g. from calculations or caching)
- you probably don't want this, but with std/boost shared pointers it's also possible to ask for a weak pointer to the shared object... that way you can test whether the "owners" of the object (which won't include you) have already finished with it and triggered its destruction

Separately, to use runtime polymorphism your `ExogenousVariationA` and ~`B` classes must actually derive from `Exogenous`, and the method you want to be polymorphically dispatched must be `virtual`.  That looks like this:

```
class Exogenous
{
public:
    virtual double interfaceMethod() const=0;
}

class ExogenousVariationA : public Exogenous
{
public:
    double interfaceMethod() const { return resultA; }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! The clone() method will do exactly what I need. Sorry for the sloppy example code.

Answer (score 5):

Your worry is valid. Since you are storing to a reference an object passed in by the client, you are trusting that client to keep the object alive while you need it. This can easily lead to problems. Of course, the same would be true if you used raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects. If the client does `delete` on the object before you're done with it, once again you have a problem.

The solution is to force the client to give you some kind of responsibility over the lifetime of the object. The way to do this is to ask for a smart pointer. Depending on your problem, you may want a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. Use the former if you want to take ownership from the client or the latter if you want to share ownership with them. Let's say you choose `std::unique_ptr`, you would then define your `Dependent` class as:

```
class Dependent 
{
public:
    Dependent(std::unique_ptr<Exogenous> exo) : exo_(std::move(exo)) {}
    double getSomething() const { exo_->interfaceMethod(); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Exogenous> exo_;
}
```

The client would use this like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<Exogenous> ptr(new ExogenousVariationA());
Dependent dep(std::move(ptr));
```

Now, when your client passes the `std::unique_ptr` to you, they're giving you ownership of the object. The object will only be destroyed when *your* `std::unique_ptr` is destroyed (which will be when your `Dependent` is destroyed, since it is a member).

Alternatively, if you take a `std::shared_ptr` then the object will be destroyed once both the client's and your `std::shared_ptr`s are destroyed.

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid smart pointers, but that's still an excellent solution. Thank you.