# Using c++ abstract classes

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, abstract-class

I'm writing a program to handle a piece of hardware (a little OLED screen). It's basic structure will be:

1. an user interface class (functions like "drawCircle", ...)
2. a class providing base commands for the OLED ("setPixel", ...)
3. a class to manage the communication interface ("sendCommand", ...)

where 1. contains 2. which contains 3., and only 1. is accessible by the user.
Changing 2. would allow to use a different OLED controller chip, and changing 3. to use a different communication interface (e.g. SPI or I2C). Let's speak about being able to change the communication interface.

Every interface needs different settings only known by the user: e.g. the I2C address may vary depending on physical configurations and the SPI interface may require the user to choose a Slave Select pin. So there must be some interface-specific setting at layer 1., but it should be "minimal"; my idea was to just provide a different constructor for every interface. Since I'd like each "layer" (1., 2. and 3.) to know as little as possible about the lower ones I'd like to use abstract classes: layer 1. should only know about a generic "device" class, and layer 2. only about an "interface".

This is one of my first practical approaches to c++ inheritance, and trying to solve my current problem by reading more or less complete and well-written articles and tutorials I got lost in too much pieces of information, I couldn't focus on this very problem.

---

Here is my problem, thus my question.

Consider the following piece of code. For simplicity I replaced all the hardware stuff with an example about numbers: `Number` stands for my `Interface` class, and `Digit` and `Text` could be `SPI` and `I2C`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// an abstract class
class Number {
public:
    // only pure virtual functions
    virtual void addOne() = 0;
};

// a class derived from Number
class Digit : public Number {
public:
    Digit(int x) : n(x) {}

    void addOne() {
        std::cout << n << " + 1 = " << n + 1 << "\n";
    }

private:
    const int n;
};

// another class derived from Number
class Text : public Number {
public:
    Text(std::string x) : n(x) {}

    void addOne() {
        std::string x;
        if     (n == "one")     x = " two";
        else if(n == "two")     x = " three";
        else if(n == "three")   x = " four";
        else                    x = "... sorry, I don't know";
        std::cout << n << " plus one equals" << x << "\n";
    }

private:
    std::string n;
};
```

If the user (i.e. the writer of the following `main` function) knows all the above code he may do like that:

```
// a class containing a Number
class C {
public:
    C(Digit x) : num(x) {};
    C(Text x)  : num(x) {};

    void compute() {
        num.addOne();
    }

private:
     Number& num;
};


int main () {

    C a(Digit(2));
    C b(Text("two"));

    a.compute();
    b.compute();

    return 0;
}
```

But what about if he does't know? I've unsuccessfully tried many possibilities, including as follows:

```
// a class containing a Number
class C {
public:
    C(int x)          : num(Digit(x)) {};
    C(std::string x)  : num(Text(x))  {};

    void compute() {
        num.addOne();
    }

private:
    Number& num;
};


int main () {

    C a(2);
    C b("two");

    a.compute();
    b.compute();

    return 0;
}
```

This gave me the following errors.

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Number' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Digit'
 C(int x) : num(Digit(x)) {};
 ^ ~~
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Number' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Text'
 C(std::string x) : num(Text(x)) {};
 ^ ~~~~~
```

Thank you for reading and for any help

Comment: I don't see why you need `Number` and `Digit` classes.  The I2C is an *interface* or could be consider as a *stream* class.  In C++, the `int` class doesn't contain methods for writing to `cout`, instead, there are helper methods, such as `operator<<`.

Comment: You could model the display as "display *has-an* interface".  Define an abstract interface class.  You could pass an instance of an interface class to your display class (another pattern is to have child Display classes for each interface).  This concept allows you to isolate the display features from the interface.  The functionality of drawing text does not require the interface; only the display requires the interface.  Also, the display's physical interface probably won't change during run-time.

Comment: For example, the I2C could derive from `Hardware_Interface`.  The Display constructor would contain a reference to `Hardware_Interface`.  When initializing the Display, pass the I2C class instance to the constructor.  If the physical interface changes, pass a different child instance of `Hardware_Interface`.

Comment: ThomasMatthews, I didn't really understand your first comment, and about the third, although I understand it I can't see a difference between the solution you proposed and the one I already tried but that I would like to change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: An abstract class as a member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213928/c-an-abstract-class-as-a-member): in your case the language helpfully forbids storing as members references that will obviously be dangling before the constructor even returns.